# Email forwarding with pipe to a program in amazon mail service (SES)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, email-parsing

I want to read an email and insert detail into `database` which i receive in my `SES`. In normal cPanel we can do it using `pipe to a program` see below image.

[image] Now i am setting up a server to amazon. So how can i develop this in amazon mail service?
I have read a `document` of [amazon recipient rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-concepts.html) and [lambda function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-lambda.html) but didn't get a proper idea how to call my code file?
I am using `php`, can anyone explain how to i create `lambda function` to call my `PHP` file or any other way?

Comment: I need the solution to the same question. Did you get the answer?

Comment: @Prateek What i did it manually is bit complex solution but it was working fantastic! 1. In SES when email received we set option and move to S3 bucket. 2. In bucket we set option to run lamda function, means when new record insert into bucket it will send those data to lamda. 3. From lambda we post data into our server and parse email data. Also i used CloudWatch Log to verify and debug all data. In conclusion i have set solution using SES, S3 bucket, Lamda, and CloudWatch log.